# PostgreSQL - Pivoting twice using two label columns and two ID columns

Tags: postgresql, pivot-table

I have a table like the following with two ID columns, two label columns, and a value column that I want to pivot.

| ID_1 | ID_2 | Analysis | Statistic | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | One | Sum | 10 |
| 1 | 1 | One | Average | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | Two | Sum | 11 |
| 1 | 1 | Two | Average | 5 |
| 2 | 2 | One | Sum | 16 |
| 2 | 2 | One | Average | 1 |

And I want the following table from my query:

| ID_1 | ID_2 | Analysis 1 Sum | Analysis 2 Sum | Analysis 2 Average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 11 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 | 16 |  |  |

How would I go about constructing such a query in PostgreSQL? I have tried to use [`CROSSTAB`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/tablefunc.html) but from my understanding that requires one ID column and one label column which doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pivot/Crosstab queries are typically done using filtered aggregation (and I find that way easier to deal with than the `crosstab()` function)

```
select id_1, id_2, 
       max(value) filter (where analysis = 'One' and statistic = 'Sum') as "Analysis 1 Sum", 
       max(value) filter (where analysis = 'Two' and statistic = 'Sum') as "Analysis 2 Sum", 
       max(value) filter (where analysis = 'Two' and statistic = 'Average') as "Analysis 2 Average"
from the_table
group by id_1, id_2;
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This was a helpful way to get what I was looking for. I appreciate you taking the time to respond.